# How can I find the lowest column from a dynamic array C++

Tags: arrays, c++11, dynamic

I am trying to find the lowest performing sales person. I keep getting an exception : Unhandled exception at 0x0105317B in Project4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x56F48BD5.
This comes up when it gets to LowPerformance = sales[Products][0];
I've tried defining the row (i.e LowPerformance = sales[10][0];) but I get the same error. Any suggestions on how to get past this exception?

```
    int main()
    {
    int Products, SalesPerson;
    cout << "Please enter the number of proudcts (1-10): " << endl; cin >> Products;
    cout << "Please enter the number of Sales People (1-10): " << endl;cin >> SalesPerson;

    srand(time(0));
    int** sales = new int*[Products];
    for (int i = 0; i < Products; ++i)
        sales[i] = new int[SalesPerson];
    int LowPerformance, LowPerformanceIndex = 0,TotalProduct = 0, TotalForSalesPerson = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row< Products - 1; row++)
    {
         for (int column = 0; column < SalesPerson - 1; column++)
        {
            sales[row][column] = rand() % 300;
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row< Products - 1; row++)
    {
        TotalProduct = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < SalesPerson - 1; column++)
        {
            TotalProduct += sales[row][column];
        }
        sales[row][SalesPerson - 1] = TotalProduct;
    }

    for (int row = 0; row< SalesPerson; row++)
    {
        TotalForSalesPerson = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < Products - 1; column++)
        {
             TotalForSalesPerson += sales[column][row];
        }
        sales[Products - 1][row] = TotalForSalesPerson;
    }

    for (int row = 0; row< Products; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < SalesPerson; column++)
        {
            cout << sales[row][column] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    LowPerformance = sales[Products][0];

    for (int row = 0; row< SalesPerson - 1; row++)
    {
        if (LowPerformance > sales[Products][row])
        {
            LowPerformance = sales[Products][row];
            LowPerformanceIndex = row;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\nThe Lowest Performing Sales Person is: " <<LowPerformanceIndex << endl;
    for (int row = 0; row< Products; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < SalesPerson; column++)
        {
            if (column != LowPerformanceIndex)
                cout << sales[row][column] << "\t";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    }
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `new` in modern C++.  Use `std::vector` (or in your case, `vector<vector<int>> sales`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the lines in your code as highlighted

```
LowPerformance = sales[**Products-1**][0];   //first element of last column

for (int row = 0; row< SalesPerson - 1; row++)
{
    if (LowPerformance > sales[**Products-1**][row])  
    {
        LowPerformance = sales[**Products-1**][row];  //lowest element of "row"th column

        LowPerformanceIndex = row;
    }
}
```

Rule: An array arr[m][n] has largest addressable index of a[m-1][n-1] as indexing starts from 0;